# Spring Boot REST Controller testing with roles

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm writing a new Spring Boot app from the scratch to have a better understanding of how its' configuration works. Right now, I'm trying to create access control which doesn't work as it should.

My UserDetailsService system uses custom UserDTO object for verifiction:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                return new UserDTO(
                        userRepository.findByEmailAddress(email)
                                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + email + "' not found."))
                );
    }
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String nickname;
    private String password;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USER_ROLE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

This is how the UserDTO class looks like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO implements UserDetails {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String nickname;
    private String password;
    private Set<RoleDTO> authorities;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private boolean enabled;

    public UserDTO(User user){
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.username = user.getEmailAddress();
        this.nickname = user.getNickname();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(RoleDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.accountNonExpired = user.isAccountNonExpired();
        this.accountNonLocked = user.isAccountNonLocked();
        this.credentialsNonExpired = user.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        this.enabled = user.isEnabled();
    }

}
```

The roles table in H2:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ROLES(ID, VERSION, AUTHORITY) VALUES
(1, 0, 'ROLE_USER'),
(2, 0, 'ROLE_MODERATOR'),
(3, 0, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```

And the controller:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public UserSimpleDTO createUser(@RequestBody UserDTO user){
    return userService.createUser(user);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public UserSimpleDTO getUserGeneralData(@PathVariable long id){
    return userService.getUserGeneralData(id);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}/details")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RolesAllowed("ROLE_MODERATOR")
public UserDTO getUserDetailedInfo(@PathVariable long id) {
    return userService.getUserDetailedInfo(id);
}
```

My role entity and DTO classes look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role extends BaseEntity implements GrantedAuthority {

    private String authority;

}
```

RoleDTO:

```
 @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class RoleDTO implements GrantedAuthority {

        private String authority;

        public RoleDTO(Role role){
           this.authority = role.getAuthority();
        }
    }
```

When I run tests as normal user, the getUserDetailedInfo() returns 200 instead of 401, but the mocked User object clearly has the `ROLE_USER` only:
[image]

What is missing so the @RolesAllowed annotation does not work properly, or is there a mistake somewhere in this code?

EDIT:

There's the test suite I use to test given method which I forgot to add:

```
@Test
@WithAnonymousUser
public void getUserDetailedInfoDoesNotAllowAnonymous2() {
    getUserDetailedInfoREST(1, 401);
}

@Test
@WithMockUser
public void getUserDetailedInfoDoesNotAllowUser2() {
    getUserDetailedInfoREST(1, 403);
}

@Test
@WithMockModerator
public void getUserDetailedInfoAllowsModerator2() {
    getUserDetailedInfoREST(1, 200);
}

@Test
@WithMockAdmin
public void getUserDetailedInfoDAllowsAdmin2() {
    getUserDetailedInfoREST(1, 200);
}
```

This is the implementation of getUserDetailedInfoREST() test method:

```
private String getUserDetailedInfoREST(long userId, int expectedStatus) {
        try {
            String response = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users/" + userId + "/details"))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().is(expectedStatus))
                    .andDo(this::mapMvcResultToUserDTO)
                    .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My custom annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@WithMockUser(value="admin",roles= {"USER", "MODERATOR", "ADMIN"})
public @interface WithMockAdmin {
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@WithMockUser(value="moderator",roles= {"USER", "MODERATOR"})
public @interface WithMockModerator {
}
```

I've also tested it by using my own `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` methods that pass the real existing users in database instead of mocked ones, also would like to know if its good or bad practice since it's hard for me to decide. It makes the tests a little less readable, but using the real users instead of mocked ones feels very temptating:

```
private static final String ADMIN_USERNAME = "admin@mail.com";
    private static final String ADMIN_PASSWORD = "admin123";

public static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder getAsAdmin(String urlTemplate, Object... uriVars) {
        return MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(urlTemplate, uriVars).with(httpBasic(ADMIN_USERNAME, ADMIN_PASSWORD));
    }

//... and the other HTTP methods+users implementations ...
```

Comment: Which mocked user? You added a lot of code but forgot the test.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I've updated the question already

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution. What was missing was the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation which I've added to the SecurityConfig.java class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//...
}
```

Now that the annotation has been added, everything works fine. The `jsr250Enabled` parameter refers to `@RolesAllowed` annotation, while `securedEnabled` would be necessary if I used `@Secured` instead.